# Can the polar crystalline polymorphs of PVDF (beta, gamma or delta) be tuned to respond to ultra-high frequency sources?

Tags: material-science, piezoelectric

I am interested in determining whether or not it is possible to tune, by polling and/or nanomaterial loading, PVDF such that it would respond to stimulus from ionizing radiation such as Gamma rays.

This mechanical movement/vibration (or response) would be imparted to the crystalline structure of the polymer by converting the energy from the particle into physical movement.